# Conditional formatting dependent on date and content in other cell

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, date

I have a date field, where I would like to do some conditional formatting.

So, if the date is more than 2 weeks ago AND the neighboring cells contains the words "Open" or Reminder" I would like the date cell to have a red background.

Unfortunately I can't get any formula to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well. You can even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) the answer. If you don't have enough reputation, your upvote will show up later, once you reach [enough reputation points](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `Open` and `Reminder` may be in some cells of column `A` and the dates are in column `B`, this formula applied to the conditional formatting of column B should solve your problem:

```
=and(or(A2="open",A2="reminder"),today()>=B2+14,B2<>"" )
```

[link to the test file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zzPBsz3xkcZOgaSowA48NTMHC_HYh05XCt88O8Vh5lI/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You do not quite specify the *"neighboring"* cells.
You also ask: *"to adapt the formula, to paste it over the complete row"*

So here are **3 options.**
**You choose** the one best suited to your needs.

1. Apply on **just the date column** when the column **before** it contains `open` or `reminder` *(**orange** in our example)*

`=AND($R3<=TODAY()-14,OR($Q3="open",$Q3="reminder"),$R3<>"")`

2. Apply on a **whole range** when the column **before** the date column contains `open` or `reminder` *(**red** in our example)*

`=AND($R3<=TODAY()-14,OR($Q3="open",$Q3="reminder"),$R3<>"")`

3. Apply on a **whole range** when the column **before or after** the date column contains `open` or `reminder` *(**yellow** in our example)*

   `=OR(AND($R3<=TODAY()-14,OR($Q3="open",$Q3="reminder"),$R3<>""),AND($R3<=TODAY()-14,OR($S3="open",$S3="reminder"),$R3<>""))`

[image]

*(**Do** adjust the formulae according to your ranges and locale)*

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed the semicolon, now the formula is valid.

I've adapted the formula according to my needs now and it works (the row turns pink):

> =and( or($F1="Offen";$F1="Erinnert");today()>=$A1+14;$A1<>"" )

[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1koh6UNIwN43JwfKqtkezo6LYt9V5uKp3yUYBk0m7Yac/)

However, I would need a second function with the same parameters, but when the date has been 4 weeks ago it needs to turn a different colour (bright red).

I've adapted the formula accordingly:

> =and( or($F1="Offen";$F1="Erinnert");today()>=$A1+28;$A1<>"" )

And added a new rule. So now I have both rules applied:
[image: Conditional Format Rules]

But only the first formula with the 14 days gets applied. Dates from 4 weeks ago are formatted the same as dates from 2 weeks ago.

So, how can I adapt the formula, so both rules get applied?

Comment: just move the condition valid after 28 days up to the first position